# Does GRUB2 see Windows 10 bootloader, if windows was installed after GRUB in GPT/EFI?

Tags: boot, windows, grub, uefi, gpt

Suppose, I have a machine with UEFI and GPT-partitioned hard drive. I have an Ubuntu system installed on it and GRUB2 in UEFI system partition.

Then I install Windows 10 and its boot loader to UEFI system partition as well. Will GRUB2 see the new Windows boot loader and allow me to chainload it? (Probably not?)

So, I'll probably have to update GRUB2 after installing Windows, if I want to chainload Windows from GRUB menu?

Comment: First you need to recover Ubuntu after installing windows

Answer (score 1):

You will need to boot into Ubuntu as Windows 10 will have over written the first stage of the GRUB boot loader from the maste boot record (MBR). You can use a Ubuntu CD in rescue mode to do this.

Then you will need to reinstall GRUB to the MBR which is an option in the Ubuntu rescue disk.

Alternatively if you have some other way to boot into Ubuntu you can use this command to update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Tom, as I've stated in the question I'm using GPT, not MBR. So, GRUB stages 1 and 1.5 are not in MBR + first 32KB of disk (MBR gap) anymore. Whole GRUB is in EFI System Partition (ESP) as well as Windows bootloader. EFI firmware will load GRUB from ESP and usually GRUB detects other bootloaders in ESP and allows to chainload them in GRUB menu. I want it to detect Windows Bootloader, but not sure, whether this requires GRUB update or not. Your answer is relevant to MBR, but not to GPT case (thanks for taking the time to write it, though).

Comment: Ah yes missed that you had installed to EFI, sorry

Comment: You will need to change the order using `efibootmgr` but I've not had to do much with efibootmgr for a while so not going to try and help and risk breaking your system :)